# xcodebuild provisioning profiles not found?

Tags: ios, xcode7, provisioning-profile, xcodebuild, ios-provisioning

I'll try to be *polite* talking about `xCode`.

**Issue:**

we updated `provisioning profiles` because prev ones are expired.
Now I can archive/build from `xCode` but can't using `xcodebuild` (which must be the same)

I did everything:

- removing, adding profiles, recreating ...
- reinstalling ... restarting...
- removing account, adding back and a lot more

`sudo xcodebuild -scheme nl.xxx.demo.iphone -workspace xxx.xcworkspace clean build`

error:

```
=== BUILD TARGET xxxWatchAppDemo Extension OF PROJECT xxx WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.
```

But when I'm archiving or building through `xCode` everything is just fine, and inside `ipa`, `embedded.mobileprovision` is actually our new `mobileprovision` with UUID `d9179316-6950-4369-94dc-b7d71bba25a1`

---

And if I **explicitly set provisioning profile** - it doesn't work out:

```
 sudo xcodebuild -scheme nl.xxx.demo.iphone -workspace xxx.xcworkspace archive PROVISIONING_PROFILE=d9179316-6950-4369-94dc-b7d71bba25a1
```

error

```
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “d9179316-6950-4369-94dc-b7d71bba25a1”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.
```

Not found??? Really?

I checked `/Users/xxx/Library/.../Provisioning Profiles/...` and it's there.
I deleted it, added, repeated it 10 times, no result.

*What kind of magic it is?*

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: 1. Do you have multiple versions of Xcode installed?
2. Can you please post the results of xcodebuild -version ?

Comment: Issue solved thanks

Comment: Hi Injectios, how do you solve it. I encounter the same as you.

Comment: @ycwjjjj Did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `Jenkins` has been running under buildagent user, however provisioning profiles weren't found.

I created symbolic link to my 
`/buildagent/Library/MobileDevice/ProvisioningProfiles/` in very root folder - `/Library/`.

That solved my issue

Comment: where is this buildagent? is it a separate user? I found that current user when running Bamboo is ROOT (that's because I started it as root....on the server machine). Any additional help would be valuable!